# Keep getting syntax error when i check code

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

This is what i entered in the code checker it is wracking my brain to get this done.
It keeps telling me I have

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' on line 8

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db= "db";
$tbl_name = "usermanagement";


$conn =  mysql_connect($localhost, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

if ( $conn->connect_error)  {
    die("Connection failed:  " .  $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change this:

```
$conn->connect_error
```

to this:

```
mysql_error()
```

Also i would use the defined variable like this:

```
$conn =  mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

Since you're using `mysql_*` API and not `mysqli_*` where you can use this: [`$mysqli->connect_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) because then you have a Object!.

Also i would recommend you to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass"; // give password of your phpmyadmin
$db= "db_name";
$tbl_name = "usermanagement";


$conn =  mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if($conn){
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
}
else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

use above code for mysql connection.

Comment: And where is the difference?

Comment: difference is in variables name that are defined. In mysql_connect using variable with different name.

Comment: Im doing this in wordpress so i have another question. It's already connected right? I should just be able to work from my tables for input?